# How should I dockerize and deploy a NestJS monorepo project?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I have NestJS monorepo project with structure as below:

```
... 
apps   
  app1   
  app2   
  app3 
...
```

If I got an idea correctly, I have possibility to run all the applications in same time, i.e. I run command and have access to apps by paths like http://my.domain/app1/, http://my.domain/app2/, http://my.domain/app3/ or in some similar way. And I need to put all apps in a docker container(s) and run them from there.

I haven't found something about this proceess. Did I undestand the idea correctly and where could I know more about deployment NestJS monorepo project?

Comment: Take a look at https://blog.nrwl.io/nx-and-node-microservices-b6df3cd1bad6

Answer (score 7):

This is how I solved it:

```
apps
  app1
    Dockerfile
    ...
  app2
    Dockerfile
    ...
  app3
    Dockerfile
    ...
docker-compose.yml
```

Each `Dockerfile` does the same:

```
 FROM node:16.15.0-alpine3.15 AS development
 WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 COPY package*.json ./
 RUN npm install
 COPY . .
 RUN npm run build
 FROM node:16.15.0-alpine3.15 AS production
 ARG NODE_ENV=production
 ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
 WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 COPY package*.json ./
 RUN npm install --only=production --omit=dev
 COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
 CMD ["npm", "run", "start-app1:prod"]
```

Where the last line should start the application so adjust that to your project naming.

Later you should build each of the images in your CI/CD pipeline and deploy them separately. To run the docker build from the root folder of the project you just need to provide a Dockerfile path for `-f` parameter, for example:

```
 docker build -f apps/app1/Dockerfile -t app1:version1 .
 docker build -f apps/app2/Dockerfile -t app2:version1 .
 docker build -f apps/app3/Dockerfile -t app3:version1 .
```

To run it locally for tests, utilize docker-compose.yml

```
  version: '3.8'
  services:
    app1:
      image: app1:version1
      ports:
        - 3000:3000 # set according to your project setup
    app2:
      ... 
    app3:
      ...
```

And start it by calling `docker compose up`

Comment: Could you kindly clarify the need for volumes?

Comment: @EmmanuelGabriel They're not needed in the most straightforward scenario. I have removed them from the example. Sorry for the confusion. That volumes would be helpful for local development when you do frequent changes to package.json and start the app using "nest start".

Comment: The example above does no seam to support references between each module in the monorepo, as docker is triggered from the api's themselves and not in the root folder.

Comment: hey @denu I was wondering how such app-level Dockerfiles can work if in a NestJS monorepo there is just one project-level package.json file. Is there anything I'm missing?